# how to generalize apachi http client post parameters

Tags: java, json, open-source, payment-gateway

I am trying to make an open-source generic payment gateways library on java.
where we will integrate all types of payment gateways so other developers can easily integrate any payment gateway in there system.

But i stuck on a point as you know data could be posted in two ways.

- old method para1=val1&para2=val2
- new one (JSON) {para1:val1, para2:val2}

For http post i choose apache http client but HttpPost accept List

```
List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<>();
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "test"));
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "testemail@domain.com"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams))
```

for json i am using Gson google json library for java.

I would like to make a parameter layer that could be easily converted in both of the form explained above.

I would like to take care of complex parameters too.
Like,
card[name]=some name & card[no] = 14444444444

your expert advise is highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you take in the request and build a data object, then pass that to your method that acts on the request?

Comment: sorry i did not understand what you mean?

Comment: Added an answer to explain my question

Comment: Are you trying to make a server that accepts both types, or a client that can send both types?

Comment: client that can post both types.

Answer (score 0):

## This answer was written based on the code being the server

### Translation layer

`Translator` translates the request into an internal representation of an action, then your `Data Controller` acts on this action object.

You could restructure your request at a translation layer, so that the `Data Controller` does not care about how the request is made, only the data contained.

This could also be used for returning data, so XML and JSON output can be created with the same `Data Controller`.

[image]

## Edit

This should be reversed, so actions are translated to requests, in the client case, which turns out to be the correct one. This reverses all arrows on the diagram

Comment: Do you know any library that do this kind of parsing or should i build one myself?

Comment: You can build it yourself, it just needs to convert HTTP requests to a data type for each request type `Request` -> `PayRequest`, `Request` -> `ListRequest` etc.

Comment: is there a way i could parse Gson JsonObject to uri?

Comment: You could, but it would be more fragile

Comment: Added update to explain my misunderstanding, and it would work for clients rather than servers

Comment: thanks for your answer but i was expecting for some code based answer.

Comment: I can write a basic version of you like, all it would do is expand out data objects to requests, with one implementation adding JSON, and the other adding fields